How to catch PanicException from pyo3?
Sometimes, some Rust-API code in Python throws a PanicException, e.g.
from mistral_common.tokens.tokenizers.mistral import MistralTokenizer

from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
from pathlib import Path

mistral_models_path = Path.home().joinpath('mistral_models', 'Nemo-Instruct')
mistral_models_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


snapshot_download(repo_id="mistralai/Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407", 
                  allow_patterns=["params.json", "consolidated.safetensors", "tekken.json"], 
                  local_dir=mistral_models_path)

tokenizer = MistralTokenizer.from_file(f"{mistral_models_path}/tekken.json")

tokenizer.decode([200000])

[out]:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c2fa3bf15389> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 tokenizer.decode([200000])

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tiktoken/core.py in decode(self, tokens, errors)
    256         ```
    257         """
--> 258         return self._core_bpe.decode_bytes(tokens).decode("utf-8", errors=errors)
    259 
    260     def decode_single_token_bytes(self, token: int) -> bytes:

PanicException: no entry found for key

The PanicException would have came from the https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3 library but I can't seem to find the right bindings to import and catch the exception.
What is the right Python library to import the PanicException object?
from ??? import PanicException
for i in reversed(range(200_000)):
  try: 
    tokenizer.decode([200000])
    break
  except PanicException:
    continue


I've tried from maturin import PanicException but it's not the right one.
